# undefined function 'view' laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I dont know what's wrong with my laravel project suddenly but every controller has this message

I tried to return the view directly from web.php and im still getting this error

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('index');
});
```

Error

```
Undefined function 'view'.intelephense(1010)
```

My other laravel projects work fine but this shows like this so its definitely not a laravel installation mistake. This project worked fine till yesterday

Comment: Does your project work still, but you are getting this error from intelephense? Did you check your ```helpers.php``` file to make sure the ```function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])``` function is there (it's probably at the end of the file)?

Comment: this is not error change your vs code `intelephense`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Can you point out exactly what to do please?

Comment: @MessagePlus you need to buy `intelephense` licence or use  `1.2.0` version

Comment: If you're using VS Code, just restart it.